# Leaflet polyline and polygon drawing not working properly

Tags: angular, leaflet

I'm using angular "10.0.4" ,"leaflet": "^1.6.0", "leaflet-draw": "^1.0.4",
and I'm trying to draw shapes. (Rectangle and circle are working perfectly) , but when I try to use the shapes that need assigning multiple points then I have to click the mouse many times so a point is assigned.
I thought is was from the browser but then I tried it on safari and nothing changed.
(and by the way, the drawing toolbar is not showing any icons if that would help).
my code:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  try {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.map = L.map('areamap', {
          center: [37.780813, -122.404750],
          // drawControl: true,
          zoom: 17,
          // attributionControl: false
        });
        var tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          maxZoom: 19,
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        });
        tiles.addTo(this.map);

        //feature group is to add the drawing features
        var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
        this.map.addLayer(drawnItems);
        // rawing controls sed to control what to use
        this.drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
          position: 'topright',
          draw: {
            polyline: {
              shapeOptions: {
                color: '#f357a1',
                weight: 10
              }
            },
            polygon: {
              allowIntersection: true, // Restricts shapes to simple polygons
              drawError: {
                color: '#e1e100', // Color the shape will turn when intersects
                message: '<strong>Polygon draw does not allow intersections!<strong> (allowIntersection: false)' // Message that will show when intersect
              },
              shapeOptions: {
                color: '#bada55',
              }
            },
            circle: false, // Turns off this drawing tool
            rectangle: {
              shapeOptions: {
                clickable: true
              },
              marker: {
                icon: iconDefault
              }
            },
            circlemarker: false

          },
          edit: {
            featureGroup: drawnItems, //REQUIRED!!
            remove: true
          }

        });
        this.map.addControl(this.drawControl);
        this.map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
          //do whatever you want; most likely save back to db
          console.log(e.layer._latlngs)
          //draw the polygon on creating (working for the rectangle and circle)
          var polygon = L.polygon(e.layer._latlngs, { color: '#43425D' }).addTo(this.map);

        }.bind(this));
      }, 0);
  
  } catch{ }
}
```

How can I draw the polyline and polygon properly ?

Comment: Maybe this library helps: [leaflet-geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the library https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman as user Falke Design suggested in the comments and it worked like charm.